# Continuity of $\int_{x+V} fdm$

Tags: continuity, lebesgue-integral

Assume $V\subset \mathbb {R}^n$, an open set. $f\in L^1(\mathbb {R}^n)$ and non-negative.

QUESTION: Consider function: $x\mapsto \int_{x+V} fdm (x\in \mathbb {R}^n)$, is it continuous? If not, is it semi-continuous?

I think the answer is on the tip of my tongue, but I cannot state any in a formal math way. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: It is uniformly continuous. A well know fact about $L^{1}$ functions  is $\int |f(x+h)-f(x)| dx \to 0$ as $ h \to 0$. You can find  a proof in Rudin's RCA.

Answer (score 0):

It is continuous if $V$ is bounded (I am not sure of unbounded $V$). This follows from what is called absolute continuity of integral which says that if $f$ is an $L^1$ function then for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that for ANY measurable set $E$ with measure less than $\delta$, $\int_E |f| < \epsilon$. This is not at all an obvious result.

Now in your situation the point is that $x+V$ and $y+V$ differ by a small set provided $x$ and $y$ are close enough. Well, on a second thought, maybe this is not too obvious. The difference seems to do with the boundary of $V$ which can be crazy :(